# How can I make various line charts in html with chart.js using multiple datasets from python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django-views, chart.js

I am doing a website in django for a project and I have to display graphics about the data I am collecting from two sensors using AWS DynamoDB. I am using python for the backend and I checked my data in python and it had the right values, but when I checked the website to see if the graphs were there, I got nothing. I am using chart.js embedded in html and I am not proficient in javascript at all, so I am having a hard time debbuging my code. The html code is as follows:

chart.html

```
{% block content %}
    <h2>Chart Data</h2>
    <br>
    <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;">
        {% for dataset in datasets %}
            <canvas id="{{ dataset.chartID }}" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></canvas>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>

        function createChart(chartID, chartType, label, data, backgroundColor, borderColor) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById(chartID).getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: chartType,
                data: {
                    labels: data.map(item => item.x),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: label,
                        data: data.map(item => item.y),
                        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                        borderColor: borderColor,
                        tension: 0.4,
                        fill: false
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'minute'  // Adjust as needed
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Define a JavaScript variable to hold the datasets
        var chartDatasets = [];

        // Loop through datasets and add them to the chartDatasets array

        for (let index = 0; index < chartDatasets.length; ++index) {
            const newDataset = {
                chartID: "{{ dataset.chartID }}",
                chartType: "{{ dataset.chartType }}",
                label: "{{ dataset.label }}",
                data: "{{ dataset.data }}",
                backgroundColor: "{{ dataset.backgroundColor }}",
                borderColor: "{{ dataset.borderColor }}",
            }
            chartDatasets[index].push(newDataset);
        }

        // Loop through chartDatasets and create charts
        chartDatasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            createChart(
                dataset.chartID,
                dataset.chartType,
                dataset.label,
                dataset.data,
                dataset.backgroundColor,
                dataset.borderColor
            );
        });


    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
# function to get the data for each station in the desired period (1 hour)

def station_data(station_str: str):

    response = dynamoTable.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('ID').eq(station_str)
    )
    items = response['Items']

    filtered_data = [elem for elem in reversed(items) if datetime.strptime(elem["timestamp"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') >= last_hour_r]

    return filtered_data

# Function to parse datetime strings

def parse_datetime(datetime_str):
    return datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# function to select the data points in each minute of the time (1 hour) that we are observing

def get_data_points(data):

    # Dictionary to keep track of unique minutes
    unique_minutes = {}

    # Select the first entry for each unique minute
    filtered_entries = []
    for entry in data:
        minute_key = parse_datetime(entry['timestamp']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        if minute_key not in unique_minutes:
            filtered_entries.append(entry)
            unique_minutes[minute_key] = True
        if len(filtered_entries) >= 60:
            break

    return filtered_entries

# function to take only the time

def take_time(datetime_str):
    # Parse the datetime string into a datetime object
    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Extract the minutes and format as a string
    minutes_str = datetime_obj.strftime('%H:%M')

    return minutes_str

def data_points(station_str):
    stat_data = station_data(station_str)
    data = get_data_points(stat_data)
    return data

def charts(request):
    y_variables = ['Temperature', 'RainHeight', 'WindIntensity', 'Humidity', 'WindDirection']
    datasets = []

    for station_str in ['station1', 'station2']:
        items_station = data_points(station_str)
        for y_variable in y_variables:
            chart_id = f'chart_{station_str}_{y_variable.lower()}'
            label = f'{station_str.capitalize()} - {y_variable}'
            datasets.append({
                'chartID': chart_id,
                'chartType': 'line',
                'label': label,
                'data': json.dumps([{'x': take_time(item['timestamp']), 'y': item[y_variable]} for item in items_station]),
                'backgroundColor': 'rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.2)',  # Grey background color
                'borderColor': f'rgba({hash(chart_id) % 256}, {hash(chart_id) % 256}, {hash(chart_id) % 256}, 1)',  # Unique border color based on chart ID
            })

    context = {
        'datasets': datasets,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/chart.html', context)
```

Comment: you would have to use `JavaScript Console` in `DevTools` in `Firefox` or `Chrome` to see if there is error message for `JavaScript` code. You may also use `console.log(text)` in your code to see information in `JavaScript Console` - and you can use it to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.